# Iteration between 2 tables SQL Query

Tags: sql

Im very new using SQL as you can see and i got a doubt about the iteration using 2 tables.

Here is the thing:

I have two tables "UsersEmails" and "Sent_Emails".

In the "UsersEmail" i have all the emails (user accounts) and in the "Sent_Emails" i have the emails sent during one period of time for example "TODAY".

So, i'd like to KNOW which email account on my "UsersEmail" table where sent TODAY and which ones werent.

I got an idea by iterating every email in my table "UsersEmail" and checking it on the table "Email_Sent" but i dont know how to do it.

I hope you guys could help me with this.

My best regards.

Comment: What you probably want is a `LEFT JOIN`, but which DBMS are you using?  ie. SQL Server, Oracle, etc.  Also, what is the relation between `UsersEmail` and `Sent_Emails` - is there a related id field or simply the email addresses?

Comment: For the record, "iterating" is against the core principles of how SQL works.  Instead, think "sets"... "I need to come up with a set of..." or "I need to operate on a set of...".  Thinking in terms of iterations can become a severe limitation and difficult block for learning SQL effectively (been there, done that...).

Answer (score 0):

You gave little information about your tables however supposedly you can write this:

sent today:

```
select * from UsersEmail e
where exists (select 1 from Sent_Emails where userEmailID=e.ID and

TRUNC(emailDate)=TRUNC(sysdate))
```

not sent today:

```
select * from UsersEmail e
    where not exists (select 1 from Sent_Emails where userEmailID=e.ID and

    TRUNC(emailDate)=TRUNC(sysdate))
```

Comment: the `exists clause` is much more inefficient then using a join

Comment: Nonsense. The only way to know for sure is check the query plan. Often the query plans are identical. Historically `exists` was often _more_ efficient (if you only referenced the clustered index) but as query planners get smarter the two approaches are generally the same.

Answer (score 0):

Emails Sent today

```
SELECT * FROM UserEmail as E
INNER JOIN sentEmails AS s ON  s.userEmailID = e.UserEmailId
WHERE s.date = YOUR_TARGET_DATE
```

Emails not sent today

```
SELECT * FROM UserEmail as E
INNER JOIN sentEmails AS s ON  s.userEmailID = e.UserEmailId
WHERE s.date <> YOUR_TARGET_DATE
```

Comment: Your second SQL will return everything that was sent yesterday, last week and last year even if it was also sent today.

Comment: @jbrooks that depends on his date column which was not given. If it is a  date '2012-01-01' then no it will not. Per OPs request OP just needs a query that will not return things for today. If OP says the date column is a datetime then my query will need to change, but without further information that is unneccessary

Answer (score 0):

you actually want to track the mails sent and cannot be sent?
if i were you, i'd add a column to my table "Sent_Emails" datetime, and set send date when i mail is sent by a user,
and in that case ,

> --MAILS SENT: SELECT * FROM SEND_MAILS WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN USEREMAILS WITH (NOLOCK) ON SEND_MAILS.USERMAILID =
>   USEREMAILS.USERMAILID  WHERE SEND_MAILS.SENDDATE IS NOT NULL
>
> --MAILS NOT - SENT: SELECT * FROM SEND_MAILS WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN USEREMAILS WITH (NOLOCK) ON SEND_MAILS.USERMAILID =
>   USEREMAILS.USERMAILID  WHERE SEND_MAILS.SENDDATE IS NULL

And with this info, you can report mails-sent on daily base.
like

> SELECT * FROM SEND_MAILS WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN USEREMAILS WITH
>   (NOLOCK) ON SEND_MAILS.USERMAILID = USEREMAILS.USERMAILID  WHERE
>   SEND_MAILS.SENDDATE = '2016-05-24'

Answer (score 0):

I like to repeat the problem to myself in English and then write the SQL. You want to compare the last email sent for a given userEmailID to the start of today.  The subquery below gives you the last email sent for a given userEmailID. The case statement will be 1 for sent today and 0 for never sent or  last email sent earlier than today.

```
SELECT E.*,
CASE WHEN MaxSentEmail > trunc_date(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SentToday 
FROM UserEmail as E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT se.userEmailID,
    max(se.sentEmails) AS MaxSentEmail 
    FROM sentEmails se
    GROUP BY se.userEmailID) as se
on E.UserEmailID = se.userEmailID
ORDER BY E.UserEmailID
```